# Find a subarray with sum 0 in O(nlogn) time complexity (Using Divide and Conquer)?

Tags: algorithm, divide-and-conquer

I have seen solutions online but all of the solutions have either O(n) or O(n^2) time complexity. I wondering if it is possible to find the subarray with sum 0 in O(nlogn) that uses no auxiliary data structure. However, we are allowed to use recursion.

Can we modify the Maximum Subarray Sum algorithm to find the solution to this problem?

The input array will have just 1's and -1's and the algorithm will find a subarray with sum 0.

Input = { 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1}

output = 1, 8 (1 being the starting index and 8 being the last index)

In this particular case, the whole input array has the sum equals to 0. So, the starting and the ending indexes reported are 1 and 8 respectively(assuming that the indexing in the array starts from 1).

Edit: We can use the solution to this problem to solve another problem. That problem is as follows.

Given an array arr of n integers, find the longest contiguous sub-array with an equal number of even and odd elements. Following is an example (indexing starts from 1):

A = {8, 2, -3, 4, 9, 6}

Answer: (2, 5). (2 being the starting index and 5 being the last index)

The only constraint is that the algorithm can't use any auxiliary data structure. The solution has to be most efficient under this constraint. Also, using recursion is allowed.

Comment: Probably, better than `O(n)` is not possible, you have to scan the array at least once.

Comment: @ZabirAlNazi, he is not asking for better.

Comment: Sorry, I missed it completely.

Comment: Does it have to be divide&conquer? Can it use recursion (and the space used that follows from recursion)? Can it be O(n)?

Comment: The restriction is that it can't use any auxiliary data structure. It does not have to be divide and conquer. It just has to as fast as possible with the constraint of using no auxiliary data structure.

Comment: OK, so then recursion is a no-go, as that uses the stack. And divide&conquer typically uses recursion, so that is then off the table as well. Can you confirm?

Comment: No, we are allowed to use recursion. It is a practice problem and I can't seem to find a solution to this anywhere online.

Comment: You should re-phrase the question maybe. It seems you're looking for any solution with O(1) memory. recursion uses memory so you shouldn't use that either. The only thing that comes to my mind is Floyd's cycle finding algorithm, but not exactly sure if it's applicable here.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I have edited the question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a recursive algorithm where the function gets the value of the previous array value (if any) and then reads the next value from the input array. If it is the same value, then it calls itself recursively and when coming back from there, it continues with the next value in the same way. If it is the opposite value it returns to the caller `true` -- to indicate that there was a zero sum. If the end of the array is encountered, the function returns `false`.

This practically means that the depth of recursion is equal to the absolute cumulative sum. So for instance, if the array is [-1, -1, -1, 1], then the recursion will go to depth 3, and it will return from level 3 to level 2 with return value `true`. At level 2 it will return `false` since the end of the array was encountered, and so it will fall out of recursion.

Whenever the return value is `true`, you can check if the covered interval is greater in size than so far encountered.

Here is an implementation of this idea in JavaScript:

```js
function zeroSum(arr) {
  let i = 0; // index in the input array, managed outside of recursion
  // Longest zero-sum interval so far. Zero based, and value at end index 
  //   is not part of the interval:
  let longest = [0, 0];

  function recur(dir) { // dir is the previous value from the array (if any)
    let start = i; // local variable
    while (i < arr.length) {
      let val = arr[i++];
      if (val == -dir) return true; // zero sum
      if (recur(val) && i - start > longest[1] - longest[0]) {
        longest[0] = start;
        longest[1] = i;
      }
    }
    return false; // no zero sum
  }

  recur(0); // 0 is passed to indicate there is no previous value
  return longest;
}

// demo
console.log(zeroSum([1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1]));
```

Comment: I have run the code and I think the second element in the longest array is off by value 1. Meaning that the answer in the case of array that you have inputted should be [0, 7] because indexing starts from 0 in your solution but the answer returned is [0,8]. Other than that, it is working just fine.

Also, is there a way that your algorithm can be used to find the subarray with equal number of odds and even in it. I think 1's in the array will represent even numbers and -1 will represent odd numbers. Do you think you can modify your solution to solve this problem?

Comment: It was intended like that. In the comments I mentioned that the value at the end-index is not part of the range. This is common practice (cf. how the `slice` method works in JavaScript, or how the `range` function works in Python). That way the subtraction of both indexes gives you the size of the range. As to modifying the solution for odd/even numbers. Please have a go at it, it can't be that difficult to do that yourself. Hint: you only have to modify this line: `let val = arr[i++];`

Comment: Ok. Got it. Thanks, Sir. Will modify it to work for array with odd and even numbers. Lastly, what do you think is the time and space complexity of your solution?

Comment: What do you think yourself? :) Hint: how many times is `let val = arr[i++];` executed overall (given that there is only one `i` variable and it doesn't change anywhere else)?

Comment: The time complexity is O(n). The space complexity is O(n) in the worst case. For instance when the list does not contain any -1, then recursion will be as deep as the list is long. The used stack space is O(n) in that case. Did this answer your question?

Comment: Yes. It did answer my question. Do you think there is a way we can solve this using divide and conquer technique?

Comment: I cannot think of a divide & conquer algorithm. Did someone tell you there is one?

Comment: My professor told me that there is a divide and conquer solution of this problem.